# Can't hide Done bar over keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have a numeric keyboard assigned for a textfield. I don't want to show any done button bar over the keyboard or inside the keyboard but I can't hide the bar.

I am trying to remove this bar:

[image: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/hc/uhkppb94cj1o.jpg]

What I tried to do is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _txtAge.delegate=self;
    [_txtAge becomeFirstResponder];
    _txtAge.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```

XCode version: 9.3 (9E145)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965340/remove-done-button-from-number-pad-upon-a-new-keyboard-loading

Comment: That didnt help me was answered 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField{
   if (textField != self.yourTextField){
      UITextInputAssistantItem* item = [textField inputAssistantItem];
      item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
      item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
   }else{
      textField.inputAccessoryView = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: Put only: self.yourTextField.inputAccessoryview = nil; in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Didn't help. Its not disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_txtAge.inputAccessoryView = nil;
```

Full code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _txtAge.delegate=self;
    _txtAge.inputAccessoryView = nil;
    [_txtAge becomeFirstResponder];
    _txtAge.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
}

// or try this

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  if (textField == _txtAge) {
    _txtAge.inputAccessoryView = nil;
  } 

  return true;
}

// or try this

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  if (textField == _txtAge) {
    _txtAge.inputAccessoryView = nil;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of those 3 ways helped. I didn't set any accessory in my code.Just selected numeric keyboard in storyboard for the relevant textfield.

Comment: try to find this keyword `inputAccessoryView` in your source code. Without inputAccessoryView for textfield, it can't show this toolbar. Or try to check any other extension or external library affecting this

Comment: I don't have any 'inputAccessoryView' code except _txtAge.inputAccessoryView = nil;